# Update Textbox with spreadsheet data from Apps Script function output in Web App

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I thought I am able to find all the answers in this forum but obviously I am stuck with one problem I cannot resolve.

I am doing a web app in Apps Script and I need to run a function, which will update textbox field values based on other text box data after clicking the button.

This is a code I have so far, which obviously is not working.

page.html (trimmed to relevant code):

```
    <script>
    
    
    function GetData(){
    
      var link = document.getElementById("songLink").value.trim();    
      
        google.script.run.GetSongRecord(link);
    
        document.getElementById("songArtist").value = foundSongArtist;
        document.getElementById("songTitle").value = foundSongTitle;
    }
    
    </script>
    
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" aria-label="default input example" id="songLink" name="songLink" style="background-color:#eee">

        <div class="col-1" style="padding: 5px; padding-top: 23px;">
          <button class="btn btn-primary align-bottom" id="getSongButton" value="Retrieve" onclick="GetData()" style="width:100px">Retrieve</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    
          <label for="songArtist">Artist: </label>
          <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" aria-label="default input example" id="songArtist" name="songArtist"  style="background-color:#eee">

          <label for="songTitle">Title: </label>
          <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" aria-label="default input example" id="songTitle" name="songTitle"  style="background-color:#eee">
```

and Apps Script part code.gs:

```
function GetSongRecord(link){
  var url= SSL_SHEET_ADDRESS;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");

  //some code here to find the data..

  htmlPage.foundSongTitle = "song title found";
  htmlPage.foundSongArtist = "song artist found";

  const htmlOutput = htmlPage.evaluate();


  return htmlOutput;


}
```

I was trying to put few pieces of various code together and I am not even sure if I am on the right path.

Comment: Your  code is not reproducible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no withSuccessHandler on google.script.run.GetSongRecord(link); so data returned to the function is not being applied anywhere in the html

These two lines make no sense in the server code

```
htmlPage.foundSongTitle = "song title found";
htmlPage.foundSongArtist = "song artist found";
```

They should be in the withSuccessHandler

Comment: Thanks!!! withSuccessHandler is what I was missing indeed...
I followed this link and gave me all answers I needed :) and I made it work.